# Why does this loop display this output?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < i) {
        System.out.println("i = " + i + "\tj = " + j);
        j++;

    }
}
```

The output is:

```
i = 1        j = 0   
i = 2        j = 0
i = 2        j = 1
i = 3        j = 0
i = 3        j = 1
i = 3        j = 2
i = 4        j = 0
i = 4        j = 1
i = 4        j = 2
i = 4        j = 3
```

My question is, why is the value of **j=0** in the second line, even though we increment it after the first line was displayed?

Also, why is the value of **i=2** twice, and **i=3** thrice?

Comment: There is a loop within a loop. You can easily see that the inner (right) one loops up to the current value of the outer (left) one.

Comment: The `j=0` appearing on the second line is generated from the _second_ itetation of the outer `for` loop.  You should really run this code in debug mode so that you can see how it works, rather than posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: It would be a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: "Why is the value of j=0 in the second line, even though we increment it after the first line was displayed?" Because it's a new `j` every time you go through the loop.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How do i run it on debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

you declared `int j=0;` within the first loop so whenever the outer loop runs value of j set to be 0.
And reason of repeated value of i is the inner loop.For every time the loop runs the value of i is same for it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you said that "until j is < than i" you increment j but the increment stops when j is = i so you have that i repeats for each increment of j.
I'm a bit confused about what your program should do but if I understood you should resolve your code like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   int j;
   for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
   System.out.println("i = "+i+"\tj = "+j);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outer **for** loop re-initialzes j to 0 in second iteration of the outer loop as it does in every iteration of the outer loop. Hence second line shows j as 0.

Since in second and third iteration of outer **for** loop, inner loop gets executed twice and thrice respectively, but outer loop variable value remains the same during the iteration of the outer loop. Hence, i=2 and i=3 is shown twice and thrice.

Answer (score 0):

The j-variable and the i-variable in your code are going like this:

- i=2:j=0->1: prints 2 times
- i=3:j=0->1->2 prints 3 times
  ...

Answer (score 0):

This concept is called nested loops. The for-loop is the outer loop, which has value of i from 1 to 4. In the inner while-loop, the value of j is initialized to 0 and it goes till j = i-1 (since the condition mentioned in while-loop is j < i).

You enter the first iteration of for-loop (i = 1). Now you enter the first iteration of while-loop (j = 0). Condition is true (0 < 1). i = 1 j = 0 is printed. In next iteration of while loop, j = 1, condition is false (1 not < 1). Hence while-loop is now exited.

Now in the second iteration of for-loop, i value is incremented (i = 2). Now you enter the first iteration of while-loop (j = 0). Condition is true (0 < 2). i = 2 j = 0 is printed. In next iteration of while loop, j = 1, condition is true (1 < 2). i = 2 j = 1 is printed. In next iteration of while loop, j = 2 , condition is false (2 not< 2). Hence while loop is exited.

As you can see, in the first iteration of for-loop print is executed only once. And in the second iteration of for-loop print is executed twice. This is because execution of print is dependent on the value of j being lesser than i (i increases by 1 every time). This pattern will repeat and for i = 3 print statement will be executed thrice and so on.

Hope you understood. If not, feel free to clear your doubts in the comments.